# Remap the docker detach shortcut

Tags: docker

Detaching from a container works with <kbd>C-p</kbd><kbd>C-q</kbd>.
But I'm used to <kbd>C-p</kbd> being going up the list of used commands. Now I have to type twice to go back one command

Is there a way to remap the docker detach command ?

Comment: You can always update the code of docker and define other shortcuts

Comment: @user2915097 I don't really know how to do that... I'm running on a rancher OS environnement, can I change the source code without having to restart the whole machine (which is not really doable) ?